# ON UPDATE 句と同じ条件での自動更新をクエリで行いたい

Tags: mysql

MySQL のカラムデフォルト値に
`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE`
をつけると更新時にだけ時刻を更新してくれる機能がありますが

カラムデフォルト指定ではなく update 文を行ったときに同様に更新時だけ時刻を更新するようなことはできないでしょうか

`UPDATE users SET mail = 'test', updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE WHERE id = 1`

のような感じで書いても syntax error になるのでカラムのデフォルトに設定する以外方法はないでしょうか

デフォルトに設定するとどのカラムが更新されても時刻も更新されてしまうので、クエリがわで更新する場合としない場合を制御したいです

１度 update クエリを行って
`SELECT row_count()`
で更新数が０でなければもう１度 update_at をセットするクエリを投げれば実現はできると思うんですが、２度に分けるのが無駄な気がするので１度にやる方法はないか保存じだったら教えていただきたいです

---

逆に DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE がついてるカラムに対して
他のカラムが更新されてもクエリで明示的に値を更新しないような指定はできないでしょうか

Comment: 1 つ目だと ON UPDATE 指定と違い同じ値で更新しても時間が更新されてしまいます。２つ目はやはり ON のところで syntax error になります

Comment: このクエリだと結局更新の有無にかかわらず時間は更新されますよね。ON UPDATE と同じく値が更新されなければ(同じ値で更新されれば)時刻も変更されないようにしたいのです

Comment: 了解です。先のコメントは後程削除します。